# Just installed ubuntu. I get boot error "couldn't read sector 0x34a28818 from hd1"

Tags: boot, 16.04, nvidia

It was done via bootable usb. Try ubuntu works just fine with the usb still in, but when I install full version and then boot without usb and try full installed ubuntu mode I get the error:

```
couldn't read sector 0x34a28818 from hd1
```

The error comes after I am stuck in purple screen for 5 to 10 minutes.

I am using msi laptop w. Nvidia drivers.

Have a nice day

Comment: what do you mean by "try ubuntu mode"? If you're not booting from the bootableUSB you should never see a "try ubuntu" option.

Comment: Whn you boot via usb you can either try it or fully install it. After installation i was told to remove the usb.

Comment: So like  I meant to say I was trying the full ubuntu thst I had just installed, and I got this error